# Requesting C level executive for considering a recruitment drive

Tags: recruitment

An IT company which we wish to work opened a new office, they held a recruitment drive for graduates/freshers(0 experience)last year . So this time we were hoping the same. But when we inquired the HR replied that no recruitment for freshers has been planned as of now. Recently my friend send  a request to the C level executive who is responsible for the growth and profitability of the company  to consider a fresher recruitment drive. He suggested me to do the same. Should I send a request? I'm confused if this approach is feasible .What is your thought on it ?

Comment: If you want to work somewhere, send in an application. What are you trying to achieve by suggesting them to hold a recruitment drive?

Comment: Do you work for the company, or are you hoping to work for the company? Edit the information into the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth We are hoping to join the company

Answer (score 10):

Don't waste your time. They're not hiring, and whatever the influencers on TikTok may have you believe, C-suite execs don't see a message from an entry level candidate and think "oh yes, this person is so good we'll change our plans to accomodate them".

Comment: Not a horrible idea though if you can connect with someone at the hiring level

Comment: @cdkMoose There are far easier ways to accomplish that though if that's your goal.

Answer (score 7):

A recruitment drive is an ad campaign, when you are relatively unknown and want to attract a lot of people. Like when you open a new location and need it staffed with hundreds of people.

They did that last year and are fully staffed and well known now.

There is absolutely no point in starting a recruitment drive.

Even if they had a job opening *for you*, a recruiting drive would be pointless to ask for. The only thing you would get is another 100 competitors for that job.

All you can do is apply for a job. If they don't have a job for you, then they don't. No letter is going to change that.

Comment: I was with you until the "No letter is going to change that.", it absolutely does happens that jobs are made for people, also at entry levels where the budget needs are low.  Take your shot, worst you can hear is no.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul But wouldn't they "make the job" when the person applies? I don't "make jobs" for people generically asking for a recruitment drive, I "make jobs" for people actually applying for a job.  At that point I'm like "we did not advertise a junior position, but this application looks really good".

Comment: Yeah for sure, but it's in a sentence about applying for a job, seemingly past the recruitment drive OP was asking about. Maybe I read it a bit wrong with my context, as it seems to imply the job cannot be made then.

Comment: The sentence is meant to say, that you can apply for a job, even if there is no recruitment drive. But if they tell you they don't have a job for you when you apply, then they don't have a job and don't want to make one for you. This is not going to change with letters to a COO about a recruitment drive.